# Preventing Nodejs MySQL SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

How do I prevent SQL injection for NodeJS? I am trying to prevent SQL Injection using the ? symbol and the req.param. But I am not able to get to work. How should I use the req.param.id correctly? Many thanks in advance.

```
    app.get('/products/:id', (req, res) => {
    conn.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) throw err;
    const SELECT_WHERE_PRODUCT_ID_QUERY = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?, $[req.param.id]`
    connection.query(SELECT_WHERE_PRODUCT_ID_QUERY, function (error, results, fields) {
    connection.release()
      if (error) throw error;
      return res.send(results)     
    });
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we should use prepared statements for that and `?` as placeholders. In order to make it work, we should pass parameters as a separate argument:

```
const query = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?';
const params = [req.param.id];
connection.query(query, params, function (error, results, fields) {
```

Another form:

```
connection.query(
    {
        sql: 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?',
        values: [req.param.id]
    },
    function (error, results, fields) {
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries) for more examples.

Comment: How does SQL injection will work in case of query like this: `SELECT * from TABLE`. No 'WHERE' clause or any conditions. Just simply preventing injection in queries that fetch complete data.

Comment: In your example SQL injection isn't possible. It doesn't matter whether a query has WHERE clause or other conditions because it can only happen when we use user-supplied data in a SQL-query. If we don't pass any arguments or we have a full control over arguments, then there is no SQL-injection.

Answer (score 1):

This should prevent SQL injection.

```
const SELECT_ALL_PRODUCT_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?'
connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCT_QUERY,[req.params.id], function (error, results)
```